# CABasic doesn't rid of image after completing the animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, cabasicanimation

I have a button in a NIB file that plays a sound and calls this method below.

```
-(void) animateHeart
{
    heartLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    [heartLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 85.0, 85.0)];
    [heartLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(150.0, 100.0)]; 

    UIImage *heartImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart.png"];
    CGFloat nativeWidth = CGImageGetWidth(heartImage.CGImage) / 3;
    CGFloat nativeHeight = CGImageGetHeight(heartImage.CGImage) / 3;

    CGRect  startFrame = CGRectMake(165.0, 145.0, nativeWidth, nativeHeight);
    heartLayer.contents = (id)heartImage.CGImage;
    heartLayer.frame = startFrame;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:heartLayer];

    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;

    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    theAnimation.duration=2.5;
    theAnimation.repeatCount=2;
    theAnimation.speed = 1.85;
    theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    theAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    [theAnimation setValue:heartLayer forKey:@"parentLayer"];

    [heartLayer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];

    theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
    theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;


}
```

The method animates the image perfectly fine but after having done so, the image is left hanging there on the view despite having set the removedOnCompletion BOOL to true. I would like to have the image disappear once the animation has completed. I'd appreciate any help I could get here.

Thank you in advance, SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `removedOnCompletion` to `YES` ensures that the animation is removed from the image's layer on completion, not that the image layer is removed from the superlayer. You need to add a delegate, track the completion event, and call `removeFromSuperview` on your view. Implement `- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation` method on the delegate, then call `[heartLayer removeFromSuperlayer]`.

Comment: I was forgetting to add a delegate. Thank you so much for your help, kind sir!

Comment: @RehatKathuria You are welcome! If the answer works for you, consider accepting it by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer. This will tell others that you are nl longer looking for a better answer, and earn you a brand new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
```

Before:

```
[heartLayer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```